# Extracting time from the date respone

Tags: javascript

```
Date.parseWeird = Date.prototype.parseWeird = function (d) {
    return new Date(parseInt(d.replace(/[^\-\d]/g, ""), 10));
};

var newDate = Date.parseWeird("\/Date(1317847200000-0400)\/");

document.write(newDate);
```

This returns me `Thu Oct 06 2011 02:10:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

I want to extract this `02:10:00` and convert this into time like this `9:30 P.M or A.M`

Comment: Where does the date come from? It looks like the default date that comes from a .NET webmethod on the server, am I right? You can solve the problem server side then (look at json serialization)

Comment: @Baszz: i have no access to server side... i have to do it in client side..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just try something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/wXvzt/

```
<h4>It is now  
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
if (minutes < 10){
minutes = "0" + minutes
}
document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + " ")
if(hours > 11){
document.write("PM")
} else {
document.write("AM")
}
//-->
</script>
</h4>
```

Comment: I don't want to display 20:12, instead i want it to be 8:12 P.M... any idea how i can do with u r code..

Comment: @JohnCooper It doesn't show 20:12, it shows the correct thing, just like you want it to.  JMax just posted the exact same thing as me.

Answer (score 1):

To display time with AM / PM, you can use this kind of script:

```
var hours = newDate.getHours()
var minutes = newDate.getMinutes()
if (minutes < 10){
  minutes = "0" + minutes
}
document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + " ")
if(hours > 11){
  document.write("PM")
} else {
  document.write("AM")
}
```